# How do I place my background color at the bottom of my content's container?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to apply a background color, with a height of 200px.  I would then like to position this background colour at the bottom of the concerned content.  I have managed to achieve this across the other web pages I am working on but struggling with this page.  No matter what I do, the background colour stays at the top of the content's container.

**HTML/PHP:**

```
 <div class="row" id="latest-products">
    <h2 id="latest-products-title-row"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-rotate-270" aria-hidden="true"></i><span id="latest-products-title">Latest Products</span><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-rotate-270" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
        <ul class="row-fluid">
            <?php
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'stock' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'orderby' =>'date','order' => 'DESC' );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; 
            ?>
                        <li class="latest-products-content">    
                            <a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                <?php 
                                    if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) 
                                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); 
                                    else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="65px" height="115px" />'; 
                                ?>
                            </a>
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                <div class="price"><i class="fa fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-rotate-270" aria-hidden="true"></i><span id="product-price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-rotate-270" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                                <div class="view/buy"><a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">View/Buy</a></div>
                        </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#latest-products{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 200px;
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

Any suggestions on where I could be going wrong here, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use background position property you need to set background-image, so to fill bottom 200px area with color you can set following:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(blue, blue 100%);
background-size: 100% 200px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center bottom;
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight.  Achieved exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the script with your browser, you will see that `#latest-products` is completely filled with the blue color. This is because `background-position` is only for `background-image`. It does not provide you any offset to just a color.

> The background-position property sets the starting position of a background image.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp


You can create an other `div`, which is `positioned absolute` at the bottom of `#latest-products`. This might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your insight Luca Jung.  For anyone reading, this suggestion also works.  I chose the other answer, simply because it explains how to 'apply' a colour to the `background-image` and limited additional work to CSS rather than having to modify HTML/PHP files as well.  Nonetheless, thanks for your 'workable' answer. :-)